# Why i cannot install Laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I installed a fresh laravel application using version `7.30.4`. When I tried to install laravel breeze, using command `composer require laravel/breeze --dev`, it gives me this error.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Package laravel/breeze has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version
```

My current version of PHP is 7.2.19

Comment: check-in your composer.json file the version of `laravel/breeze` and `php version  laravel/framework` you have to install at least php: version ` ^7.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes due to compatible version in your composer.json file. To  fix this issue, change the composer.json file "platform" configuration:

```
"platform": {
            "php": "7.3"
 }
```

Then execute `composer install` or `composer update`

or you can run the below command:

```
composer config platform.php 7.4.3
```

Laravel breeze required PHP version `7.3` and as you said your PHP version is `7.2.19` so you have to update it.